# A counting problem.

Tags: combinatorics

There are $n ≥ 3$ married couples attending a daily couples
therapy group. Each attendee is assigned to one of two round tables, so that
no one sits at the same table with his/her spouse. The order of seating at
each table remains fixed once and for all.
Initially, $s$ of the attendees have contracted a contagious disease. For
each person P, consider P’s two neighbors at the table, as well as P’s spouse
(who, of course, sits at the other table). Each day, if at least two of these
three people are sick, then P gets sick too, and remains sick forever.
Eventually everyone gets sick. Across all possible seating arrangements,
what is the smallest possible value of $s$?

Try: By PHP and simple reasoning I got $s=n+1$. Is it true? Im surprised at the simplicity of the answer.

Comment: This is meant to hold for any initial configuration of the $s$?  If so, then $s=n$ is not possible...as we could just infect one whole table, leaving the other table permanently safe.  So all that's needed is to show that $n+1$ works.  Am I reading the problem correctly?

Comment: @lulu I understand the problem statement so that we ma choose a "defensive" seat arrangement, and after that the adversary may choose the $s$ originally sick persons. A smart adversary won't be so stupid and infect one table completely

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  Yes, that's another logical reading. Is it clear to you that $n$ is insufficient for your interpretation?

Comment: @angryavian That scenario would stop spreading soon

Comment: Problem M4 from the [PRIMES 2017 problem set](http://math.mit.edu/research/highschool/primes/materials/2017/entpro2017usa.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

In the graph with an edge between spouses and neighbours, colour an edge blue if exactly one of its vertices is sick and green otherwise. Thus a healthy vertex gets sick if it has two blue edges, and by getting sick all three edges change colour. Thus every newly infected person decreases the number of blue edges by at least one. Incidentally, the last person getting infected (we may assume wlog. that concurrent infections take place milliseconds apart) will turn three blue edges green.
If we start with $s$ infected people, there are at most $3s$ blue edges, hence at most $(3s-3)+1$ additional people can be infected. We conclude that $4s-2\ge 2n $, or
$$ s\ge\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil=\begin{cases}m+1&n=2m\\m+1&n=2m+1\end{cases}.$$
Now let's see if this bound can always be achieved:

- For $n=2m$ even, infect every second man and one of the women. 
  Then after one day, all men are sick. From then on, the sickness will spread step y step among the women.
- For $n=2m+1$ odd, again infect all even-numbered men $M_2,M_4,\ldots, M_{2m}$ and also one woman $W_1$. After one day, the men alone will infect $M_2,M_3,\ldots, M_{2m-1},M_{2m}=M_{n-1}$. Additionally, $W_1$ and $M_2$ infect $M_1$. After that, $M_n$ is infected from $M_1$ and $M_{n-1}$, and the infection among the women occurs as above.

So indeed, is suffices to infect $$\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil $$
"strategically" positioned people originally.

*Remark:* The number does not depend on the seat arrangement!

Comment: But we need to find the minimal $s$ for all possible positions. does not that mean that we need to find the maximal $s$ among all minimums for a particular case?

Comment: @mudok I think I showed that: No matter what the seat arrangement is, it is impossible to infect everybody by starting with less than $\lceil (n+1)/2\rceil$, and it is always possible to infect everybody by startiung with $\lceil (n+1)/2\rceil$

Comment: Suppose there are $3$ couples $(A_i,B_i);\ i=1,2,3$. Such that only $A_1,B_1$ are sick. Then $A_1$ and $B_1$ sit at different tables as directed. then no one gets infected next.

Comment: Suppose $A_1,A_2,A_3$ are sick and sit together at one table. Then their better-halves $B_1,B_2,B_3$ sit at the other table on the first day. Then no one becomes sick any more.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Your argument for the lower bound is really amazing!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen can you please explain my examples I gave above? How your lower bound works in that scenario?

Comment: Nobody is interested to clarify my doubts? :(

Comment: @mudok Hagen von Eitzen clarified his setup in an earlier comment: the seating is set first, and then the $s$ initially sick people are chosen by the adversary with the intent to infect everyone. You seem to have a different setup where the sick people are chosen first. You should clarify the setup of  your problem in your initial question.

Comment: @angryavian thank you sir. Only you understood my confusion. yes I thought that the sick people are chosen first. then the minimal $s$ would be $n+1$ right?